# redirect to android app when launching vue mobile website in browser

Tags: android, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a mobile website created using vue js and I have an android app as well for that same mobile website. What I need is when user is going to vue mobile website using android phone user should be redirected to android playstore for downloading the relevant app if user is not already installed the app. If user is already installed the app, then when user visits the mobile web site should be launched the already installed app. Since I am using vue js to create the app, in `vue.config.js` file inside `pwa` object, there's a `manifestOptions` object to configure the `related_applications`. So my attempt is as below. Assume there's an app called example in playstore.

```
    pwa: {
       manifestOptions: {
          "prefer_related_applications": true,
          "related_applications": [
            {
              "platform": "play",
              "id": "com.example.example",
              "name": "example",
              "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.example"
            }
          ]
       }
    }
```

By using this it's coming the download banner popup. But need to add the redirection popup as well. So maybe I need to add another property in `manifestOptions`. Can someone help me to achieve this challenge?

Comment: I am also looking for this, please answer if you already had a solution